# How can I do p2p payment in my iphone app?

Tags: ios, payment, payment-processing

I'm working on an app-idea that enable users to sell goods and services through the app. For this to work I need to be able to pay users, much like uber drivers are paid for their rides or how snapcash transfers money from one user to another.

Does Apple have any framework to do this in iOS apps?

Does it have to be country specific maybe? So that every user register their bank account and my company takes money from one users credit card and makes a bank transfer to the receiving user.

Any input or pointers to where to find more info on this is much appreciated.

Comment: I found that [v.zero](https://www.braintreepayments.com/v.zero) by braintree might be what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

No, Apple does not have a framework to do this, unless you use Apple Pay (in which case it's not a P2P payment).

Your solution will have to be country specific and more. I.E. bank specific. You'll have to have deals in place with each bank you want your system to work with.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would like to have a checkout option on the mobile. If this is the case, there are lot of options available. It depends on country and what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Please more information to assist you.